# Invalid condition in a MySQL UPDATE's WHERE clause - updated EVERYTHING - instead of NOTHING

Tags: mysql, mariadb, where-clause

What I meant to write:

```
UPDATE items_ordered_list ords
    SET ords.last_ordered='2019-10-16 10:49:23'
    WHERE ords.cust_id='11656165';
```

What I *actually* wrote:

```
UPDATE items_ordered_list ords
    SET ords.last_ordered='2019-10-16 10:49:23'
    WHERE ords.cust_id-'11656165';
```

Instead of giving me some sort of error that the `WHERE` clause wasn't a logical expression - it just happily went along updating everything.  I have a backup - and a way to recover the previous value - but - the "-" is adjacent to the "=" on the keyboard - took me a while to see this.

I tried it with a `SELECT / LIMIT` statement - and sure enough - it brought back as many records as I set in the `LIMIT`...

Is this a flaw...or "by design"?  Is there some way that "ords.cust_id-'11656165'" evaluates to "TRUE"???

Please let me know - usually, for big / dangerous updates, I'll do a `SELECT` or `EXPLAIN` first - just to be sure that the SCOPE returned is reasonable - this little bit of code, I just change the cust_id - but - I accidentally deleted the "=" - and when I re-typed it - I (obviously) made a typo...any help / advice will be appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all your `cust_id` customer ID values be either *less* or *greater* than the integer `11656165`, then by casting rules the following expression would be a positive/negative number, which also evaluates to true, e.g.

```
ords.cust_id - '11656165'
```

For example:

```
SELECT 11650000 - '11656165'; -- returns -6165
```

and:

```
SELECT
    IF(11650000 - '11656165', 'TRUE', 'FALSE') -- returns TRUE
```

The lesson here is to check your code before running it.  In this case, a typo still resulted in a valid update query, which may have damaged your data.